# Forcing dropbox to omit particular type of file extensions?

Tags: linux, dropbox, data-transfer

I use Dropbox to save my numerical work on the fly - it's very convenient since I don't have to think about saving code every time when I make a change - but there is one flaw. You see, my `.cpp` files, `.png` files and .tex files are quite light, but during the computation my program generates a lot of `.dat` files (extension is arbitrary), which can weigh up to ~500 MB or even 1 GB.

After that my Dropbox account says it won't be syncing anymore. Well, deleting `.dat` files all the time when I end my work is as problematic as saving backups - plus, often I need generated data to check solutions without generating data again.

Is there any option to tell Dropbox (on Linux, but I think all versions are the same) to avoid some extensions and save only particular?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Dropbox Sync client supports this as of now. I don't think there is a workaround.

You could try moving the bigger .dat files to another folder in Dropbox and stop them from being synced(You'd also have to enable Selective Sync for this).

Comment: Well I was looking for something more smart, like 'ignore .* files, or *dat files'